# Changing The width of jquery autocomplete dropdown for particular id

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, dropdownbox

Hi i am using Jquery Auto Complete dropdown in my page.But there are Lot of dropdowns. i want to change the width for particular ids.Can u please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

I found the dropdowns on my autocompletes size themselves to fit the content.

I'm using an override on the item render function to add formatting html to each of the result items, and by sizing the items within the item render function (which I've overridden), the dropdown adjusted to fit.

I used a variable to store the desired width as I needed it dynamic based on the size of a parent div as I'm using resizeable 'portlets'. I calculate the desired width in the ajax success callback, and then in the render function I set the width using the style property on the outer item container (a table per item for now as it worked better for me that all the alternatives I tried!) :

```
$("#tbCustomerSearch").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "CustomerData.asmx/GetAutoComplete",
            data: "{ 'prefixText': '" + request.term + " }",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                var width = $('#customerSearch').width() - 50;
                searchResultTableWidth = width;
                response($.map(data.d.Matches, function (item) {
                    return { clicked: item, value: data.d.CleanedText }
                }))
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function (e, ui) {
        CustomerSearchSelect(ui.item.clicked);
    }
});
```

The function I use to override the default item render:

```
function PatchAutocomplete() {

$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    var re = new RegExp(this.term, 'i');

        var t = "<table class='searchResults' style='width: " + searchResultTableWidth + "px'><tr><td>" +
                            item.clicked.CustomerName.replace(re, function (matchText) { return "<span class='matchedText'>" + matchText + "</span>" }) +
                        "</td><td class='alternateCell'>" +
                        ((item.clicked.MatchedName != "") ?
                                    ("<span class='alternate'>Alternate: <span class='alternateName'>" +
                                        item.clicked.MatchedName.replace(re, function (matchText) { return "<span class='matchedText'>" + matchText + "</span>" })
                                    + "</span></span>")
                                 : "") +
                                 "</td></tr></table>\n";
        return $("<li></li>")
          .data("item.autocomplete", item)
          .append("<a>" + t + "</a>")
          .appendTo(ul);

};
```

}

However, if you just need a static size, try this css:

```
ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu { width: 400px; }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this in CSS

```
#<idHere> + .ui-menu {
     width:<widthHere>;
}
```

The + in CSS is for adjacent siblings so you should be able to match the menu dropdown from a specific div or input ID with that.

Answer (score -3):

`$('#foo')` will get you a JQuery object containing the node with `id="foo"`.  That should get you started.  It's what's known in JQuery as a selector.  If you're going to be doing much work in JQuery, it would behoove you to spend some time on http://api.jquery.com/ learning about things like selectors, as they're fairly core to being effective with the language.